# What is the word described in this poem?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

My beginning is a time for a leader to lead.

My middle is a type of insect seed.

My end is a talk that’s shorter than a screed.

I increased a problem that was losing all its speed.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **Reignited**

My beginning is a time for a leader to lead.

> **Reign** - the period of rule of a monarch.

My middle is a type of insect seed.

> **Nit** - the egg or young form of a louse or other parasitic insect

My end is a talk that’s shorter than a screed.

> **TED** - [TED talks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TED_(conference)) are usually reasonably short.

I increased a problem that was losing all its speed.

> **Reignited** - made something such as a disagreement or worry that was disappearing grow stronger.

Comment: You got it! Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had a decent idea on the last two lines, and managed to hammer in something resembling a fit on the first two, so I'll just go ahead and guess

> **Deterioration.**

*My beginning is a time for a leader to lead.*

> In military terminology, a "**det**" is short for "detachment", meaning that a smaller group is sent on a special mission, so it's time for a leader to lead.

My middle is a type of insect seed.

> The seeds of a strawberry (and a couple of other plants) come in an aggregate fruit called an etærio, or **eterio**. I think I need a bigger hammer to fit any insects in here, though.

My end is a talk that’s shorter than a screed.

> An **oration** is a longish talk, but not as long as a screed.

I increased a problem that was losing all its speed.

> **Deterioration** means that things start to go from bad to worse.